# mat-dialog with tabs not working in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, dialog, mat-tab, mat-dialog

I want to show 2 tabs while opening a dialog. But dialog only consists tab texts, Tabs are not working. Here is my code,

**dialog-overview-example-dialog.component.html**

```
<mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1</mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 2">Lorem ipsum</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

**example.component.html**

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.css']
})
export class ExampleComponent {

  animal: string;
  name: string;

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }

  openDialog(): void {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
      width: '80%',
      height: '80%',
      position: {
        top: '10vh'
      },
      data: { name: this.name, animal: this.animal }
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
      this.animal = result;
    });
  }

}

@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog.component.html',
})
export class DialogOverviewExampleDialog {

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

}
```

Tabs are not coming up inside dialog[image]

Reference : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5zbvzd

Comment: Are you importing MatTabsModule in your project? A good way to help you to  find out the problem would be to provide a stackblitz project started from scratch rather than a custom one working.

Comment: I have a separate module called material module. There I have been importing all material modules including tabmodule. I have imported material module in abc module which contains this example.component.html particular component.

Comment: Is your console showing any error information?

Comment: No. It is not showing any errors

Comment: You should recreate your situation in Stackblitz because your posted code isn't complete.